# Where to set variables so that they aren't null on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

My webpage lets a user select one or more tools from a list of available tools (by dragging from the "available" list to the "selected" list). There is a `HiddenTools` hidden field that is updated every time the two lists change- the `<li>` in the `ToolsActive` list are stored as a comma separated list of ids in the `HiddenTools`. When the user clicks "Save", the value in the `HiddenTools` is stored in the database.

aspx page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenTools"/>

/*<li> can be dragged from one list to the other. Every time the lists 
change, HiddenTools gets updated with the contents of ToolsSelected  
list, formatted as a comma separated string */

<ul id="ToolsAvailable">            
    <%foreach (KeyValuePair<int,string> tool in unusedTools){ %>
        <li id='<%= tool.Key %>'> <%= tool.Value %> </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>

<ul id="ToolsActive">
     <%foreach (KeyValuePair<int,string> aTool in selectedTools){ %>
         <li id='<%= aTool.Key %>'> <%= tool.Value %> </li>
     <% } %>
 </ul>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
```

code-behind:

```
public partial class Settings
{
    protected ToolPreferences prefs;

    protected Dictionary<int, string> tools;
    protected Dictionary<int, string> unusedTools;
    protected Dictionary<int, string> selectedTools;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int AccountId = getAccountId();
         if(!Page.IsPostBack){
             prefs = new ToolPreferences(AccountId);
             PopulateTools();
         }
    }

    private void PopulateTools()
    {
        tools = getPossibleTools();
        unusedTools = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        selectedTools = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        List<int> selectedList = new List<int>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefs.Tools))
        {
            selectedList = prefs.Tools.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> aTool in tools)
        {
            if (selectedList.Contains(aTool.Key))
            {
                selectedTools.Add(aTool.Key, aTool.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                unusedTools.Add(aTool.Key, aTool.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnSavePreferences_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolPreferences tp = ToolPreferences (AccountId);
        tp.Update(HiddenTools.Value);
    }        

}
```

The issue is that after PostBack, the following error appears:

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

with the following line highlighted:

> `<%foreach (KeyValuePair<int,string> tool in unusedTools){ %>`

If I move the following two lines out of the `!PageIsPostBack`check, I don't get that error when the page reloads after postback, but I also don't see the changes the user made to the tools lists until the page is reloaded another time.

```
prefs = new ToolPreferences(AccountId);
PopulateTools();
```

**Where can I set the tools variables so that the "Object reference not set" error doesn't occur?**

Comment: In page load before checking for postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request is handled by a fresh instance of your page-class, so all instance variables are reset (as you found out).

Values you want to keep over requests should be stored in [ViewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb386448(v=vs.140)) (to store values between postbacks in *this* page) or [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178581(v=vs.140)) (to keep values between multiple pages).

NB: do *not* store those values in static variables. They do keep their values between postbacks, but are also shared between all visitors.